# Deployer service in windows don't work

Tags: 2013, deployer

I've installed the Tridion 2013 with the Deployer Service on Windows 2012 Server. When i try to publish a dummy page, the process fails on Deploying phase. The log writes the following lines:

> com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, null, null
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:197) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:175) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_13]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_13]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_13]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_13]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_13]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_13]>

My configuration file for test is like this:

```
<Deployer Version="7.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_deployer_conf.xsd">
    <Processors>
        <Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor">
            <Module Type="SchemaDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy"/>
            <Module Type="PageDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy">
                <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>
            </Module>
            <Module Type="BinaryDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy"/>
            <Module Type="ComponentDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy"/>
            <Module Type="TemplateDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy"/>
            <Module Type="PublicationDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy"/>
            <Module Type="TaxonomyDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy"/>
            <Module Type="ComponentPresentationDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy">
                <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>
            </Module>
            <Module Type="StructureGroupDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy"/>
        </Processor>
        <Processor Action="Undeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor">
            <Module Type="PageUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageUndeploy"/>
            <Module Type="ComponentPresentationUndeploy"
                    Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationUndeploy"/>
            <Module Type="TaxonomyUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyUndeploy"/>
            <Module Type="StructureGroupUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupUndeploy"/>
        </Processor>
    </Processors>
    <Queue>
        <Location Path="C:\Temp" WindowSize="20" Workers="2" Cleanup="true" Interval="2s"/>
    </Queue>
    <HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="10000000" Location="C:\Temp" InProcessDeploy="true"/>
    <TCDLEngine>
        <Properties>
            <Property Name="tcdl.dotnet.style" Value="controls"/>
            <Property Name="tcdl.jsp.style" Value="tags"/>
        </Properties>
    </TCDLEngine>
         <License Location="C:/Tridion/config/cd_licenses.xml"/>

</Deployer>
```

And the storage:

```
<Configuration Version="7.1"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <Global>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
            </Policy>
            <Features>
                <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>
        </ObjectCache>
        <Storages>
            <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
                <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="127.0.0.1" />
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                    <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
                    <Property Name="password" Value="*********" />
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\pruebas" />
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
    </Global>
    <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
        <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
        <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
        <Publication Id="1" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
            <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
        </Publication>
    </ItemTypes>
    <License Location="c:/Tridion/config/cd_licenses.xml"/>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: To run Java on Windows, you also need the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable (with the same bitsize as the Java instance you intend to use). Can you please check that you have it installed? You can download it from this location: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999

Comment: yes, it's installed, but i've reinstalled the mvc++ 2010 sp1 one more time to try, but the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your configuration seems good, I think you probably forget a jar.

Could you check if there is a SQL driver for java lib (sqljdbcx.jar) in your lib folder?

Comment: PERFECT!, it was the key! i've copied every jar one more time and this time worked perfect!